# Binding an action to an element inside an iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Suppose the generic structure of my web page looked like this. Where I had an iframe that self contained a page.

```
#maindocument <html>
...     
 <iframe ...>
   #document <html>
   ...        
   <form ..>
     <input class ="button"...>
      ...
```

If I have a JS file called maindocument.js how can I attach an action to the button within the form of the iframe so that if I clicked it an alert message would pop up saying I clicked it?

Or when clicked called e.preventdefault() or any function ect...How can I bind such an action?

I tried using:

```
 $("#iframe_id").contents().find('.button').bind("click", function() { alert("Test"); });
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: can you show a working example, something like a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the content of iframe after the code html, put:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(e) { alert("ok") });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If I put  $("#iframe_id").contents().find('.button').bind("click", function() { alert("Test"); }); within the Chrome console it works so I thought the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for the reference of jquery inside the iframe webpage.
if not add a reference of it and try using **on** instead of bind as **bind** is deprecated in the latest versions. it will work.

try from the parent window that host the iframe

```
$("#iframe_id").contents().find('.button').on("click", function() { alert("Test"); });
```

Hope it helps ....